# Update Sequelize column with appending to the existing array on SQLite

Tags: typescript, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a model which looks like

```js
import {Optional, Model, Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

/*This is the Product model used to save the data about products*/
export interface ProductAttributes {
    productId: number;
    title: string;
    userName: string;
    sellerReview: string;
}

export interface ProductCreationAttributes extends Optional<ProductAttributes, 'productId'> { }

export class Product extends Model<ProductAttributes, ProductCreationAttributes> implements ProductAttributes {
    productId!: number;
    title!: string;
    userName!: string;
    sellerReview: string;

    public static initialize(sequelize: Sequelize) {
        Product.init({
            productId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            title: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            userName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            sellerReview: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                get: function () {
                    return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('sellerReview'));
                },
                set: function (val) {
                    return this.setDataValue('sellerReview', JSON.stringify(val));
                }
            }
        },
            {
                sequelize,
                tableName: 'products'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I have a controller from where I will insert and update the values into the model as follows:

```js
import express from 'express';
import { Router, Request, Response, RequestHandler } from 'express';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';
import { Readable } from 'stream';
import { Sequelize, where } from 'sequelize';

/**
 * This method is to add new products/services to the products model.
 */
productController.post('/add',
    (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        Product.create(req.body)
        .then(product_added => res.send(product_added))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
    });

/**
 * This method is to edit a product in the products model.
 */
productController.put('/edit/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    Product.findByPk(req.params.id)
        .then(found => {
            if (found != null) {
                found.update(req.body).then(() => {
                    res.status(200).send('Product updated successfully.');
                });
            } else {
                res.status(404).send('Product not found.');
            }
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
    });
    productController.put('/addNewReview/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        Product.findByPk(req.params.id)
            .then(found => {
                if (found != null) {
                    found.update(
                        {sellerReview: Sequelize.literal( req.body.sellerReview)},
                        {where: {productId: req.params.id}}
                    ).then(() => {
                        res.status(200).send('Riview added successfully.');
                    });
                } else {
                    res.status(404).send('Product not found.');
                }
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
        });
export const ProductController: Router = productController;
```

I wanted to update the row with a new review by concatenating it to the existing value of the 'sellerReview' column. For example:
Existing column is `["review1", "review2", "review3"].`
When I update it to add `["review4"]`, I wanted it to be
`["review1", "review2", "review3", "review4"]`.

The input to create a new row is like:

```
{
"title": "product1",
"userName": "user1",
"sellerReview": ["review1", "review2", "review3"]
```

}

For updating,

```
{
"title": "product1",
"userName": "user1",
"sellerReview": ["review4"]
```

}

Using 'Sequelize.literal' doesn't work for me. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What error did you get with `Sequelize.literal`?

Comment: @Anatoly It just rewrites the previous value of the column instead of concatenating. Like ```["review4"]``` instead of ```["review1", "review2", "review3", "review4"]```

Comment: If Sqlite has something like `CONCAT` function then you can try it with `sequelize.fn('CONCAT', sequelize.col('sellerReview'), req.body.sellerReview)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that `sellerReview` has `setter` and `getter`

Comment: @Anatoly It is inserting this, ```{"sellerReview": {"fn": "CONCAT",
        "args": [
            {
                "col": "sellerReview"
            },
            [
                "review4"
            ]
        ]
    },```

Comment: Please look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `setter` and `getter` for `sellerReview` field you cannot use Sequelize.literal or Sequelize.fn.

So you can just take the existing value of `sellerReview` from `found` and combine it with a new value like this:

```
found.update({sellerReview: found.sellerReview.concat(req.body.sellerReview)}, { where: {productId: req.params.id}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution did not work for me. (It should be ```.concat``` I guess?). I changed it to ```.concat``` but it gave me a 500 error from the database. Can you please help me with this...

Comment: @ Anatoly ```found.update({sellerReview: found.sellerReview.concat(req.body.sellerReview)}, { where: {productId: req.params.id}})``` worked for me!! I think the problem is with JSON.parse. Thanks for the help!!